Given that $a+b+c+d+e+f=0,a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3+e^3+f^3=0$, the sum of any pair $a,b,c,d,e,f$ isnt $0$,show that $(a+c)(a+d)(a+e)(a+f)=(b+c)(b+d)(b+e)(b+f)$
After using that
$(x+y)^3 = x^3 + y^3 + 3xy(x + y)$
and that
$(x + y)(x + z) = x²+(y+z)x + yz$,
I got stuck at point where I know that the folowing equation is valid:
$(a + c)(a+d)(c+d) = -(b+e)(b+f)(e+f)$.
It looks like I'm on the way to find the solution but I'm struggling to move on from here.
Can anyone please help?
Thanks in advance!
P.S.: All numbers are real numbers.
[Edited on 09/11/2024 to include a different solution]
I'll first show how I got to (a + c)(a+d)(c+d) = -(b+e)(b+f)(e+f)$
I have found a much simpler solution than the ones linked on the duplicate of my question. Here it is:
$a + c + d = - (b + e +f) $
$(a + c+ d)^3  = [- (b + e +f)]^3$
$(a + c)^3 + d^3 + 3(a+c) \cdot d \cdot (a + c + d) = -[(b + e)^3 + f^3 + 3(b+e) \cdot f \cdot (b + e + f)]$
$a^3 + c^3 + 3ac(a+c) + d^3 + 3(a+c) \cdot d \cdot (a + c + d) =-[ b^3 + e^3 + 3be(b+e) + f^3 + 3(b+e) \cdot f \cdot (b + e + f)]$
$a^3 + c^3 + d^3 + b^3 + e^3 + f^3 + 3ac(a+c) + d^3 + 3(a+c) \cdot d \cdot (a + c + d) =-[3be(b+e) + 3(b+e) \cdot f \cdot (b + e + f)]$
Now, we know that $a^3 + c^3 + d^3 + b^3 + e^3 + f^3 = 0$. So,
$3ac(a+c) + 3(a+c) \cdot d \cdot (a + c + d) =-[3be(b+e) + 3(b+e) \cdot f \cdot (b + e + f)]$
We can now divide both sides by 3, hence:
$ac(a+c) + (a+c) \cdot d \cdot (a + c + d) =-[be(b+e) + (b+e) \cdot f \cdot (b + e + f)]$
We can now factor each side of the equation as follows:
$(a+c)(ac + d \cdot (a + c + d) =-[(b+e)(be + f \cdot (b + e + f)]$.
So,
$(a+c)(ac + d (a + c) + d^2) =-[(b+e)(be + f (b + e) + f^2)]$.
We can now use the identity $(x + y)(x + z) = x²+(y+z)x + yz$ to get
$(a+c)(a + d) (d + c) =-[(b+e)(b + f) (f +e))]$.
Let's call the equation above Eq. A.
Notice that if we start with $a + c + d = -(b + c + d)$, we can follow the exact same steps above to find
$(a+e)(a + f) (f + e) =-[(b+c)(b + d) (c +d))]$.
This is going to be Eq. B.
Now, if we multiply the respective sides of Eq. A by Eq B, we have
$(a+c)(a + d) (d + c)(a+e)(a + f) (f + e)  = -[(b+c)(b + d) (c +d))] \cdot \{-[(b+e)(b + f) (f +e))]\}$
Notice that $(f + e)$, and $(c + d)$ can be canceled as they appear on both sides of the equation and from the hypothesis we know they are not zero. So,
$(a+c)(a + d)(a+e)(a + f)   = (b+c)(b + d)(b+e)(b + f)$

Welcome to Math SE. FYI, I found the duplicate question using an Approach0 search. That search also comes up with the AoPS thread complex numbers.
